# How send Generic List as a wcf service parameter from silverlight without using Add Service Reference?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have a Client and aServer application.

For the Client application I use SilverLight and forthe Server application I use WCF.

I provide services for SilverLight application using ChannelFactory.

So there is no "Add Service Reference" and there is no generated code for proxies. My problem is I have a Serviceoperation with accept GenericList as a parameter For example

```
GetALL(List<PeopleDTO> peopleList)
```

In client side I create the list and call the service method. There is no error message but in server side the parameter "`peopleList`" ***has NULL value***!

I also have another service method which returns "List" and it works fine and return a list of "PeopleDTO". I dont know what is happening when the service method needs a generic list as a parameter.

I Do search on the Internet but I could not find the solution. Most of the solutions are related to using "Add Service Reference" in SilverLight application instead of using ChannelFactory.

Comment: Can you post some code on how your ServiceContract looks like? And the code you are using from your client app

Comment: did you check the trace log file on whether the data is posted to the WCF service.

Comment: Look at RIAServices. These are specifically designed to work with Silverlight.